# we have ? in a url and ajp converts it to %3F

Tags: apache, character-encoding, ajp

with the Mod_jk connector we have this in our /etc/apache2/sites-available file:

`RewriteRule /$ /op_ugw/orderportal/home?switchprofile=RecyledPlants [L]`

This works fine. and www.recycledplants.com will get you to the correct place.

However on Ubuntu 10.04 server we setup ajp instead of mod_jk . so we have

ProxyPass / ajp://10.1.1.1:8009/op_ugw/orderportal/home?switchprofile=RecyledPlants
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://10.1.1.1:8009/op_ugw/orderportal/home?switchprofile=RecyledPlants

When I try to get to recycledplants.randrinc.com  (url for testing) I get a 404 error and

description: The requested resource (/op_ugw/orderportal/home%3Fswitchprofile=RecyledPlants) is not available.

the ? has been converted to %3F.

Is there a way to stop Apache from converting the ? to %3F.

Hope this makes sense.
thanks
Ann

Answer (score 0):

got some pointers over on Java Ranch and was able to figure it how.  Here is what I did:
Ok, here is what works:

/etc/apache2/sites-available  file with no parms/redirect (just the top section of the file ):

`NameVirtualHost 10.1.1.1:80`

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

```
     ServerName ugw.randrinc.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/ugw/

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / ajp://10.1.1.1:8009/op_ugw/orderportal/home
    ProxyPassReverse / ajp://10.1.1.1:8009/op_ugw/orderportal/home

    <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>

<Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
   etc...etc... etc..
```

Here is what it looks like when you need to redirect, in my case i am passing parms and the application does the redirecting:

`NameVirtualHost 10.1.1.1:80`

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

```
    ServerName recycledplants.randrinc.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/recycledplants/

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / ajp://10.1.1.1:8009
    ProxyPassReverse / ajp://10.1.1.1:8009

    <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteRule \/$ /op_ugw/orderportal/home?switchprofile=RecyledPlants [L]
    </Proxy>
<Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
  etc....etc....etc
```

Hopes this helps someone.  Also I am running on Ubuntu 10.04 on an Amazon cloud server.
Having a little trouble formatting, but I think you can read.
Ann

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly: **Add a "NE" to the end of the RewriteRule**.

This flag prevents mod_rewrite from applying the usual URI escaping rules to the result of a rewrite. Ordinarily, special characters (such as '%', '$', ';', and so on) will be escaped into their hexcode equivalents ('%25', '%24', and '%3B', respectively); this flag prevents this from happening.

```
RewriteRule \/$ /op_ugw/orderportal/home?switchprofile=RecyledPlants [L,NE]
```

You can read more about how this works in the apache mod_rewrite documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html